# Service Worker is grabbing everything

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have just recently started fiddling with service workers and am having a situation where no matter what file(s) I tell it to add to the cache, it is adding *everything*. Now, this would normally mean less work for me toward an offline application, but I am a bit confused. So the cache seems to have two methods of adding requests to it, `.add()` and `.addAll()`, with the latter being capable of receiving an array of requests, but even with just `.add()` with a request hardcoded into it, absolutely all requests seem to end up in the cache.

The code I have is as follows:

```
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        //console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration in progress.');
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js').then(function() {
            //console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration complete.');
        }, function() {
            //console.log('CLIENT: service worker registration failure.');
    });
    } else {
        console.log('CLIENT: service worker is not supported.');
    }
```

... this being in the actual page calling the service worker, and the service worker itself:

```
var cacheName = 'cache';

self.addEventListener('install', (e) => {
    console.log('[Service Worker] Install');
var appShellFiles = [
];

e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
          console.log('[Service Worker] Caching all: app shell and content');
      return cache.add('assets/images/boy.svg').then(function() {
        // requests have been added to the cache
        console.log('added')
      });
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then((r) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Fetching resource: '+e.request.url);
        return r || fetch(e.request).then((response) => {
                  return caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Caching new resource: '+e.request.url);
            cache.put(e.request, response.clone());
            return response;
          });
        });
      })
    );
  });

self.addEventListener('activate', (e) => {
    e.waitUntil(
      caches.keys().then((keyList) => {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map((key) => {
          if(key !== cacheName) {
            return caches.delete(key);
          }
        }));
      })
    );
  });
```

... but in here `.add('assets/images/boy.svg')` used to be `.addAll(appShellFiles)`, which itself used to contain individual files, but seemed to ignore the list and still cache everything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Look at this code:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (e) => {
    e.respondWith(
      caches.match(e.request).then((r) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Fetching resource: '+e.request.url);
        return r || fetch(e.request).then((response) => {
                  return caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
            console.log('[Service Worker] Caching new resource: '+e.request.url);
            cache.put(e.request, response.clone());
            return response;
          });
        });
      })
    );
  });
```

It saves everything in the cache dynamically/on the fly/automatically. Your code is correct – initially it only caches the one file you mentioned. But immediately as the app starts up, the SW caches everything.

Another way to look at this problem of "caching everything": *caching everything* doesn't even mean *anything*. The browser has no way of knowing what that "everything" means for a particular site. It could be 4 or 4000 assets. Once this is realized, it is only a matter of finding the correct piece of code.

Comment: ok so first of all i thought the fetch event is the event that returns existing elements from the cache, so probably my bad there. But thank you, will try to sort it out!

Comment: No, it's not that =) Event listener for the fetch event interferes with _all_ fetch events. It does not necessarily have anything to do with caches – that is completely up to you. It is correct that the fetch event listener is the one to respond with results from the cache, but it isn't inherently so. There's no automatic anything, only if you write the code (as you did). I heavily suggest you to read through Google's introduction and all the rest of the SW materials: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers

Comment: "i did" is an overstatement, i merely copy and adapt code. But yes I agree i need to look more into it! thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @AndreiS. that's good. Especially with Service Workers it is *very wise* to actually read through the docs and guides since they're an easy way to make your site completely unusable in various ways. I would say they're dangerous in some sense.